# How to recursively simplify a mathematical expression with AST in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, abstract-syntax-tree

I have this mathematical expression:

```
tree = ast.parse('1 + 2 + 3 + x')
```

which corresponds to this abstract syntax tree:

```
Module(body=[Expr(value=BinOp(left=BinOp(left=BinOp(left=Num(n=1), op=Add(), right=Num(n=2)), op=Add(), right=Num(n=3)), op=Add(), right=Name(id='x', ctx=Load())))])
```

and I would like to simplify it - that is, get this:

```
Module(body=[Expr(value=BinOp(left=Num(n=6), op=Add(), right=Name(id='x', ctx=Load())))])
```

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html), I should use the NodeTransformer class. A suggestion in the docs says the following:

> Keep in mind that if the node you’re operating on has child nodes you
> must either transform the child nodes yourself or call the
> generic_visit() method for the node first.

I tried implementing my own transformer:

```
class Evaluator(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_BinOp(self, node):
        print('Evaluating ', ast.dump(node))
        for child in ast.iter_child_nodes(node):
            self.visit(child)

        if type(node.left) == ast.Num and type(node.right) == ast.Num:
            print(ast.literal_eval(node))
            return ast.copy_location(ast.Subscript(value=ast.literal_eval(node)), node)
        else:
            return node
```

What it should do in this specific case is simplify 1+2 into 3, and then 3 +3 into 6.
It does simplify the binary operations I want to simplify, but it doesn't update the original Syntax Tree. I tried different approaches but I still don't get how I can recursively simplify all binary operations (in a depth-first manner). Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm also trying to solve this with ast.walk but find the same error: the changes I perform don't persist.

Comment: Take note that ``1 + 2 + 3 + x`` already gets optimised to ``6 + x`` before execution. The disassembly (``dis.dis('1 + 2 + 3 + x')``) allows to see this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three possible return values for the `visit_*` methods:

1. `None` which means the node will be deleted,
2. `node` (the node itself) which means no change will be applied,
3. A new node, which will replace the old one.

So when you want to replace the `BinOp` with a `Num` you need to return a new `Num` node. The evaluation of the expression cannot be done via `ast.literal_eval` as this function only evaluates literals (not arbitrary expressions). Instead you can use `eval` for example.

So you could use the following node transformer class:

```py
import ast

class Evaluator(ast.NodeTransformer):
    ops = {
        ast.Add: '+',
        ast.Sub: '-',
        ast.Mult: '*',
        ast.Div: '/',
        # define more here
    }

    def visit_BinOp(self, node):
        self.generic_visit(node)
        if isinstance(node.left, ast.Num) and isinstance(node.right, ast.Num):
            # On Python <= 3.6 you can use ast.literal_eval.
            # value = ast.literal_eval(node)
            value = eval(f'{node.left.n} {self.ops[type(node.op)]} {node.right.n}')
            return ast.Num(n=value)
        return node

tree = ast.parse('1 + 2 + 3 + x')
tree = ast.fix_missing_locations(Evaluator().visit(tree))
print(ast.dump(tree))
```

Comment: " The evaluation of the expression cannot be done via ast.literal_eval as this function only evaluates literals (not arbitrary expressions)"

But I used literal_eval to evaluate the expression (1+1) and it returned 2. And that's what I want: to simplify operations where no variables are involved. Couldn't I also use literal_eval?

Comment: @GuillermoMosse If you are using Python <= 3.6 then you can use `ast.literal_eval`. In Python 3.7 *"constant folding has been moved from the peephole optimizer to the new AST optimizer"* (see [what's new](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#optimizations) as well as these issue [bpo-29469](https://bugs.python.org/issue29469) and [bpo-11549](https://bugs.python.org/issue11549)).